# How to count % of difference between two numbers in Powershell

Tags: powershell, math

i'm fairly new to powershell. I have a task to create a script that reads a log of a job run, counts the number of items by line, and then compares that count to a previous run and throws an Event log if the difference in percent exceeds 30 percent.

I'm having some difficulty finding out how to compare the job count run and compare difference in percent.

so far i have this code:

```
$TodayCount = $todayrun.Count
$YesterdayCount = $yesterdayrun.count
$DifferenceCount = ($TodayCount - YesterdayCount) +1
```

That counts the number of ints between each too, but i need to find a percentage different between the two runs so I can throw an IF statement that if difference in items is > 30 Write to event log .. for instance today count could equal 2000 lines and yesterday could equal 1800 lines or 2200 .. i just need to store the percentage difference.

Hope that makes sense, and please be gentle :)

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the percentage increase: First, work out the difference (increase) between the two numbers you are comparing. Then divide the increase by the original number and multiply the answer by 100.

I've made an *assumption* that you would want to check if it's greater than or equal to +30% **or** less than or equal to -30%.

If you want greater than and less than then change `-ge` to `-gt`and `-le` to `-lt` respectively.

```
$TodayCount = $todayrun.Count
$YesterdayCount = $yesterdayrun.count
$DifferenceCount = $TodayCount - $YesterdayCount +1
$percentageDifference = $DifferenceCount / $TodayCount * 100

if(($percentageDifference -ge 30) -or ($percentageDifference -le -30))
{
    Write-Output "Percentage difference is +/-30%"
}
```